# Integrating audio files (specifically MP3) with c++ Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, mp3, irrklang

I've been using the irrKlang library to play all sorts of audio files, mostly MP3s, for my applications. However those are console applications since the irrKlang engine is built that way. Now I would like to build GUIs integrated with audio and music (specifically a music player), but I haven't been able to incorporate irrKlang with it.

So is there any other music library that will allow me to integrate music files (preferably MP3s, even though I know they're extremely complicated) with Win32 API? Also, is there any way I could be able to integrate the existing irrKlang library with a GUI written in Win32 API (with no MFC)?

(I am using c++, irrKlang 1.5.0, CodeBlocks 13.12, and Windows 8)

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you can't use irrKlang in a gui app?

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks for your comment. I didn't look into it much at all, but it seemed the irrKlang engine only ran in console c++. I also tested it a few times with Win32 API code, but every time when the audio would play, a console window would pop up loading the engine, and then play the music in console. So in essence, I don't know why irrKlang wouldn't play with GUI, I just haven't figured out how to work it.

Comment: @BoBTFish So how would I be able to use irrKlang with GUI and Win32 API?

Comment: No idea, never used it, but the website gives the impression it's a pretty big commercial product, used for games and the like, so the idea that it only works in console apps really doesn't feel likely to me.

Comment: Just read into that. It does seem the library is used for a wide range of programs. Well thanks anyways